# Visual Basic.Net stopping user selecting listbox items

Tags: vb.net, listbox, selecteditem

How do I make it so that the user can't select the first two items in a list box. I'm trying to make a program that runs when the user changes their selected index, but the first two items are going to be headings for a table so I do not want the program to run if the user tries to select them.

Comment: Can add the important parts of your code please?

Comment: Can you use a ListView instead of a ListBox?  You can create column headings with a list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just unselect them again:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex < 2 Then
        If ListBox1.Items.Count < 2 Then
            ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
        Else
            ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 2
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

It does have -5 elegance points, the kind you can get back by using a Label above the ListBox or by using a ListView instead.

Comment: No idea what elegance points are, but I can Google it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As with Hans' answer, it's not very clean but might I suggest:

```
ListBox1.RemoveAt(0) 
ListBox1.RemoveAt(1)
```

It won't work if the list is databound, but if that's the case then you might like to try

```
ListBox1.DataSource = linqQuery.Skip(2).ToList()
```